# Do ERC721 BatchMetadataUpdate token ranges have to be consecutive token ID numbers?

Tags: solidity, tokens, nft, erc-721, meta-data

I am implementing a ERC721 contract with NFT metadata on-chain and will have a function that can update the metadata if needed. Therefore I would like to emit the BatchMetadataUpdate event after this update function.

The event is as follows:

```
BatchMetadataUpdate(uint256 _fromTokenId, uint256 _toTokenId);
```

Does anyone know if the range of token ID's need to be consecutive e.g. 1,2,3,4 ?
My Token ID's are a hash of the token name and therefore cannot be determined by a fixed range of consecutive numbers,  can I input the first token ID minted and the last and expect this to work?
Thanks for any help on this.